# Regular expression in Java that matches format STATUS [a number] [a math operator] [another number]

Tags: java, regex

I have to validate that the server response matches following format

```
STATUS [a number] [a math operator] [another number]
```

Number can be any integer and math operator would be +,/,- or *.

How can I validate this using a regular expression in Java code?

Comment: Have you tried to write a regex yet?

Comment: Can you show an actual string example instead of using placeholders?

Comment: What sort of numbers? Can the numbers contain ',' and '.' and superscript for exponents? Are Roman numerals OK? Octal? Hexadecimal?

Comment: A valid example would be "STATUS 5 + 10".All numbers will be between 1 and 1000.They would not contain any superscript or exponent or ,

Comment: @hwnd Can you please repost your answer.I think it for deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your could use the following regex using `matches()` to validate.

```
if ("STATUS 5 + 10".matches("STATUS *\\d+ [-+/*] \\d+")) { ...
```

Comment: You need to escape * and /

Comment: I will try with that.Also,the line should end with \n.i.e STATUS 5 + 10\n. Do i need to specify that after *\\d+?

Comment: Thought the above works , it can accept more than one white spaces between 5 and + which is not expected. I tried changing it to *\\d+ [:blank:] *[-+/*] [:blank:] *\\d+ but it fails. How can I ensure exactly one white space "5 + 10"?

Answer (score 0):

It will be some thing like this

```
STATUS [0-9]*  [+*/-]  [0-9]*
```

Answer (score 0):

\From Oracle's documentation:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a*b");
 Matcher m = p.matcher("aaaaab");
 boolean b = m.matches();
```

Now `"a*b"` is a regex here and you need to replace with the regex you need, something like:

```
"[\\d]+[+-\\*\\/]{1}[\\d]+"
```

but it might be different depending on what you need (you didn't specify how long the numbers should be etc.)